# Qt qmake configuration file win32-g++

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5, qmake

I am trying to run PyQt's config.py file. However the Qt 5.1 qmake executable will not generate a makefile. The error given is "Could not find qmake configuration file win32-g++". I installed Qt 5.1 (community license) using the GUI installer on my Windows 7 machine, and updated my path to include the Qt bin directory.

Does anyone know how to make the qmake configuration files available after installing Qt 5.1?

Comment: Do you really need to compile from source? If not, just use the [binary packages](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5).

Comment: Thank you! I was following an older tutorial and your comment helped :)